# php7.2.11 - pthreads-unable-to-initialize-module-in-windows-10

Tags: php, pthreads

I'm trying to test pThreads, but I can't make it work...

I foollow several tutorials and questions in SOf [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751202/php7-startup-pthreads-unable-to-initialize-module-pthreads-in-windows-7)

My configuration is:

PHP : php-7.2.11-Win32-VC15-x64
and downloaded las phpThreads
php_pthreads-3.1.6-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip

I execute php from commmand line, so I don't need to add nothing in apache ( i'm using laragon !)

The error is:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.2.11-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\php_pthreads.dll (No se encontr el proceso especificado.), C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.2.11-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\php_php_pthreads.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el mdulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in 
C:\laragon\www\mkte_booking_v2\web\SimpleWebRequest.php on line 4
```

So, if I got it right  maybe I have to downgrade to php 5.3 ?

pThreads on windows doesn't have activity since:

```
2/13/2016  9:48 AM        <dir> 3.1.6
```

Any suggestion ?

Best Regards

Comment: I think you have a typo in your path `C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.2.11-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\php_pthreads.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've written, it looks like there could be a couple problems.

The first possibility is that PHP is unable to locate the php_pthreads.dll as the error indicates, and you need to modify your include path or copy the dll to your /ext folder.

Possibility 2, which is more likely, is that you're attempting to load a PHP 7.0 VC14 module in PHP 7.2 VC15.

Try pthreads 3.1.6 VC15 for 7.2 -- https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/pthreads/3.1.6/